# Lotus Notes create session doesn't return an object and hangs

Tags: java, session, lotus-notes, lotus

I have been using the following code to create sessions since 7-8 months and retrieve records successfully.

```
s = NotesFactory.createSession(
                ReadJNDIProperties.getProperties("notes/host"),
                ReadJNDIProperties.getProperties("notes/username"),
                ReadJNDIProperties.getProperties("notes/password"));
        db = s.getDatabase("", nsf);
```

Where 's' is the notes session object.

Today suddenly, the code is not able to establish sessions with domino and when i test that portion of code, it just sits there. the NotesFactory.createSession() function never returns me an object.

Please tell me what might be causing it ?

Thanks in advance.
-Tushar

Comment: Did password expired/changed :) ?

Comment: check parameters you are passing to `createSession()`

Comment: @knut - the password and the user name were updated and then I checked against the code and it didn't work either.

Comment: @Rafael - Everything was what it was earlier. I checked with Lotus notes admin and they don't see any errors as well on their side. it's so frustrating. please help

Comment: @Tushar-46835 If you create a separate small java app, that just gets notes session using the same credentials. Will it work ?

Comment: @Rafael - I tried that as well. that's how I came to know that, the session creation doesn't work.
I just hangs there. nothing is returned from the function

Comment: @Tushar-46835 if you replace `ReadJNDIProperties.getProperties` to **constant** and **correct** strings will your application hang? If yes, then try to run your application in another environment with another server. Seems that there is something broken with the server components.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov - I did that and it hangs as well. and the problem is we are in process of decommissioning lotus notes hence all the domino servers have already been decommissioned. this is the only one left which I am using to migrate data from.

Comment: I would install a local domino server (on the workstation) using the same server.id, names.nsf and all system domino databases. Then I would try to instantiate notes session. And If it would work, then I would reinstall domino server with the same id/names.nsf/notes.ini to migrate the information. Upon reinstall just backup (move) all informational databases to an external (non domino-data) folder. And when reinstall is done return databases back.

Comment: The first thing you should do is run the Lotus Notes client on the same machine that you are running your code on and attempt to open the same database on the same server. What happens if you do this?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov: Hi Rafael and Richard,
I restarted the DIIOP services on the server and also rebooted it and that worked. Do you know what might have caused the server to stall ?

Comment: @Tushar-46835 sorry, I have no idea about the reason

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

- Check the web access for the user accesing his/her mail (https://serv.example.com/mail/user.nsf)
- Maybe you need to load the DIIOP task at the server.
- What jar are you using? I had problems with NCSO.jar but I could connect with Notes.jar
- Make sure that the host is an internet name server ("serv.example.com" or just "serv") and not the Notes server name ("serv/MyExampleBusiness")
- Another reason could be that you upgraded Lotus Notes to 9.x recently as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779685/notes-9-0-1-notessession-returns-null-in-vbscript).